# Understanding what happens when you use references of arrays and append them to dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

If someone has a better question title, i'm all <s>ears</s> eyes...

I just spent a while on this problem and found the issue was my understanding. I had the following code below (note the comment marked by "## <<--").
It basically takes a dictionary (summaryTotal, e.g. data below) which contains a summary of alarms: both total counts and a list of the summarised alarms and some info about them. The actual alarms are within `summaryTotal['Alarms']` which is an array of dictionaries. My function filters this full list of alarms by the alarm `source` and produces the same format as `summaryTotal`, but filtered.

The line of code I was having issue with was this one:
`summaryFiltered['Alarms'].append(alarm)`
In this line, `alarm` is really a reference to an element from the `alarmsTotal` list. The `alarmsTotal` list itself is a reference to `summaryTotal['Alarms']`.
When I used this line of code and appended `alarm`, the function at the bottom of the code `system.util.jsonEncode` (external function to change a python object into a json encoded python object - not too sure on the details), was always coming up with a 'too many recursive calls' error. When I changed what I was appending by creating essentially a new `alarm` dictionary within a new object and set it to the values within the actual `alarm` object, then the `jsonEncode` function started working and not raising recursion exceptions.
I'd like to be able to explain why that is?
When I'm appending `alarm` to my new array, I think I'm appending the *reference* of the `summaryTotal['Alarms']` object to it, for example `summaryTotal['Alarms'][20]`... ?

```
summaryTotal = ['ActiveUnacked':0, 'ActiveAcked': 2, 'ClearUnacked': 23,
                'Alarms':
                [
                  {
                    "name": "Comms Fault",
                    "eventTime": "Fri Mar 05 12:25:27 ACDT 2021",
                    "label": "Comms Fault",
                    "displayPath": "Refrigeration MSB4 MCC PWM Comms Fault",
                    "source": "FolderA/FolderB/FolderC/MSB4 MCC PWM Comms OK",
                    "state": "Cleared, Unacknowledged"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "Comms Fault",
                    "eventTime": "Fri Mar 05 12:28:46 ACDT 2021",
                    "label": "Comms Fault",
                    "displayPath": "Refrigeration MSB4 MCC PWM Comms Fault",
                    "source": "Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/MSB4 MCC PWM Comms OK",
                    "state": "Cleared, Unacknowledged"
                  }
                ]
               ]

alarmsTotal = summaryTotal['Alarms']
summaryFiltered = {'ActiveAcked':0, 'ActiveUnacked':0, 'ClearUnacked':0, 'Alarms':[]}
for alarm in alarmsTotal:
    if pathFilter in alarm['source']:
        alarmInfo = {'name':alarm['name'],
                     'label':alarm['label'],
                     'displayPath':alarm['displayPath'],
                     'source': alarm['source'],
                     'state': alarm['state'],
                     'eventTime': alarm['eventTime']
                    }
        summaryFiltered['Alarms'].append(alarm) ## <<-- to fix the code, I added `alarmInfo` above and appended `alarmInfo` instead of `alarm`
        if alarm['state'] == 'Cleared, Unacknowledged':
            summaryFiltered['ClearUnacked'] += 1
        if alarm['state'] == 'Active, Unacknowledged':
            summaryFiltered['ActiveUnacked'] += 1
        if alarm['state'] == 'Active, Acknowledged':
            summaryFiltered['ActiveAcked'] += 1 

ret = system.util.jsonEncode(summaryFiltered)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List changes unexpectedly after assignment. How do I clone or copy it to prevent this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-how-do-i-clone-or-copy-it-to-prevent)

Comment: @0x5453 Thanks, that's super handy to read! I guess what I still don't understand is, regardless whether I append the newly created dict `alarmInfo` or if I append the existing dict within the `summaryTotal['Alarms']` array, aren't these both just references to dict objects? Or are these stored differently because one dict is contained within an array inside of a dict, and the other is just a standalone dict?